# Windows Forms - Scrollbar starts in middle of form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a Windows Forms application, and the main form (`Form1`) is too long for the window so a Scrollbar appears (because I turned `AutoScroll` on).  Problem is, the scrollbar starts scrolled down slightly, i.e. not at the top.  It seems to be positioning the TabControl (which is slightly down on the page) at the top.

How do I get the scrollbar for `Form1` to start at the top?  I would want to do this:

```
Form1.VerticalScroll.Value = 0;
```

but `Form1` doesn't seem to have that property.

Comment: Probably the control with least `TabIndex` is located in your `TabControl`. You can correct tab index of controls or as an alternative you can select a control which is located at top of the form as active control in `Load` event of the form, for example `this.Button1.Select();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the ScrollToControl function:

```
protected override Point ScrollToControl(Control activeControl) {
  return this.DisplayRectangle.Location;
}
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks very much.